# atoi() - from char to int

Tags: c++, atoi

```
char c;
int array[10][10];
while( !plik.eof())
{
    getline( plik, text );
    int string_l=text.length(); 
    character_controler=false;
    for(int i=0; i<string_l; ++i)
    {
        c=napis.at(i);
        if(c==' ') continue;
        else if(character_controler==false)
        {
            array[0][nood]=0;
            cout<<"nood: "<<nood<< "next nood "<<c<<endl;
            array[1][nood]=atoi(c); // there is a problem
            character_controler=true;
        }
        else if(c==',') character_controler=false;
    }   
    ++nood;
}
```

I have no idea why `atoi()` doesn't work. The compiler error is:

```
invalid conversion from `char` to `const char*`
```

I need to convert `c` into int.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi

Comment: You are iterating over the length of `text` yet you are getting the character from `napis` using `c=napis.at(i);`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `char` is already implicitly convertible to an `int`:

```
array[1][nood] = c;
```

But if you meant to convert the char `'0'` to the int `0`, you'll have to take advantage of the fact that the C++ standard mandates that the digits are contiguous. From [lex.charset]:

> In both the
>   source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal
>   digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

So you just have to subtract:

```
array[1][nood] = c - '0';
```

Comment: c isn't 0. it can be any number

Comment: I think from memory that C++ doesn't mandate ASCII though it does mandate consecutive characters for the digits. So, while your `ch - '0'` code is right, the reason is slightly off.

Comment: @paxdiablo Right you are

Answer (score 0):

[atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) expects a `const char*`, which maps to a `c string` as an argument, you're passing a simple `char`. Thus the error, `const char*` represents a pointer, which is not compatible with a `char`.

Looks like you need to convert only one character to a numeric value, and in this case you can replace `atoi(c)` by `c-'0'`, which will give you a number between 0 and 9. However, if your file contains hexadecimals digits, the logic get a little bit more complicated, but not much.